# AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver causes many ANR with FirebaseAnalytics

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I recently updated to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
```

which is adding `AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver` to my app manifest.xml just like this https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver

Since then, I'm having a lot (almost 5 per hour) of :

```
Broadcast of Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER flg=0x10 pkg=my.app 
cmp=my.app/com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver (has extras) }


"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x766f4ce8 self=0x7a52814c00
  | sysTid=9106 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7ad934d560
  | state=S schedstat=( 9992336593 1304413016 9382 ) utm=658 stm=341 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fd7055000-0x7fd7057000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000007c600  /system/lib64/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8)
  #01  pc 0000000000014d48  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+148)
  #02  pc 0000000000014c18  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+60)
  #03  pc 0000000000130028  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, int)+44)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:326)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:181)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7094)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Is there something I can do for it or should I just wait for an update from Firebase...

Comment: Did you solve this?